# TFS without any branch

Tags: tfs

Do you really need a Branch to **CheckIn / CheckOut** Code in **TFS** i.e, just add files to a folder ?

What would be advantage to Branch in that case ?

Comment: Are you using TFVC or Git in TFS?

Comment: Using Visual Studio Online as well as on premise TFVC

Comment: So you are using TFVC in both TFS and VSO. Cool..

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a branch to check in and check out.

Branches however provide you with the ability to make changes to more thank one version of your code at once. Lets say that you have one folder at $/ProjectA/MyAwesomeApplication/Master. You can happily work away, checking in and releasing. At some point you find a bug in production that needs fixed immediately. However MASTER is well beyond what was last released and you don't want to deploy those changes yet.

You know which build is deployed and thus which changeset. You can branch MASTER at that changeset (the past) and create $/ProjectA/MyApplication/QuickFix. There you can fix that bug and ship, then merge back into MASTER and delete that branch.

Now obviously this is expensive and time consuming. A better way would to move forward and just ship what is in MASTER. If you have feature flags and good testing them you should be able to do that. There are however always those exceptions to that rule, and that's where branching comes in.

If you are using Git in TFS rather than TFVC the story is different.